# Data Migration Issue. Need advice

Tags: migration, database-migration, data-migration

My data was migrated from one database into another one. And I'm concerned about the results. In old database we had a table like this: [Old Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V9xb.png)

In a new database it looks like this:
[New Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciOC5.png)

I find it really inconvenient that different cars are listed in one row if they have the same delivery date. Sometimes I need statistical reports on how many cars of each brand and color we have, what is the average age and etc. Would it be possible to get accurate statistical reports if data is organized like this? I think they need to rebuild the whole table. But they say it can stay like that. I showed to them an example of the reports from the old database where each car was listed on a separate row, and they did some formatting in cognos and provided me with a very similar report, with one single column for each attribute and each car listed on a separate line. My question is, will it be OK to leave the structure of the table like in the new database, or is it better to make it the same as it was in the old database? Please, advice. I need accurate numbers in statistical reports, that's my main concern.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you shared the new structure seems flawed. It seems like you need a schema change after n number of cars. That would be poor DB design.

From a reporting point of view it is not an issue, you can always do a pivot on a data column etc. It is more expensive than the old schema, but if there are other reports that are cheaper, that would be a trade off.